# Is CancellationTokenSource mandatory when CancellationToken is requested?

Tags: c#, .net, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

This [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28VS.100%29.aspx) can be written without the use of `CancellationTokenSource`, one can use CancellationToken directly.

Is it OK to use a `CancellationToken` directly or is it something that should never be done? I have not seen any example of direct use on MSDN and that makes me wounder if it is OK to do so.

**Update**

Cod below expands on accepted answer with a small set of test cases that demonstrate that `CancellationToken` is immutable and thus `CancellationTokenSource` has to be used if control of token is desired.

It is worth mentioning that Token property on `CancellationTokenSource` *returns new object with each call*.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CancellationTokenProps() {
  CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken(canceled:false);
  Assert.IsFalse(token.IsCancellationRequested);
  Assert.IsFalse(token.CanBeCanceled);
}

[TestMethod]
public void CancellationTokenSourceProps() {
  CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
  CancellationToken token1 = source.Token;
  CancellationToken token2 = source.Token;
  Assert.IsFalse(Object.ReferenceEquals(token1, token2));

  Assert.IsTrue(token1.CanBeCanceled);
  Assert.IsFalse(token1.IsCancellationRequested);
  Assert.IsFalse(source.IsCancellationRequested);
  source.Cancel(true);
  Assert.IsTrue(source.IsCancellationRequested);
  Assert.IsTrue(token1.IsCancellationRequested);
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215784/why-is-cancellationtoken-separate-from-cancellationtokensource. Duplicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You can't cancel a [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) directly without invoking [`CancealltionTokenSource.Cancel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which means that using only the Token is pretty useless (it will never be signaled, you could just use `CancellationToken.None` instead)

Cancellation works where one side has the means to notify cancellation (`CancellationTokenSource`) and the other side needs to observe that and get cancelled (with a `CancellationToken`)

---

*You *could* simply create a `CancellationToken` directly while passing a `bool` signifying if the token is already cancelled or not, but you *can't* change that throughout the application's lifetime, so the use cases are very rare.

Comment: Good answer. A big benefit is that the thread creator maintains control of cancellation. Threads given the token can't arbitrarily call `Cancel` and potentially make other threads halt prematurely.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't ever want to cancel, you can simply pass `CancellationToken.None`.

If you're writing a public async API, you should make your method accept a `CancellationToken` and pass it to any methods you call, so that your own callers can cancel you.
(make sure to roll back any state in case of cancellation)

Comment: The OP, if I understand correctly, is asking about cancellation without a CTS and not how not to use a CT.