# Should I use CancellationTokenSource or CancellationToken to Cancel a task in .NET

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I see `CancellationToken` and `CancellationTokenSource` both have `IsCancellationRequested` getter method. Most examples pass `CancellationToken` to the method that is executed inside the `Task`. It looks to me by using any of these, call can return. If I use `IsCancellationRequested` of `CancellationTokenSource`, will it be a problem? When I should I throw  exception (by using `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`) or just return from the method if there is cancellation request as shown in the following code?

```
class Program
{
    //If CancellationToken is passed then it behaves in same way?
    public static int TaskMethod(CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
    {
        int tick = 0;
        while (!tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.Write('*');
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            tick++;
            //token.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        //Should I just return or use ThrowIfCancellationRequested?
        return tick;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
        Task<int> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => TaskMethod(tokenSource));
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to stop the task");
        Console.ReadLine();
        tokenSource.Cancel();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", task.Result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215784/why-cancellationtoken-is-separate-from-cancellationtokensource

Comment: Pass a method a `CancellationTokenSource` only if you want it to do the cancelling. If the method is the thing being cancelled, pass it a `CancellationToken`.

Answer (score 8):

1. `CancellationTokenSource` holds and controls `CancellationToken` instance. The task method is expected to use the cancellation token but not modify it. If you pass `CancellationTokenSource` to a method, the method gets full control of the cancellation token. So the method should take `CancellationToken` as a parameter.
2. The behavior of the method after cancellation request is up to you. There is no rule that the task should be in canceled state (throw `TaskCanceledException`) if it has been terminated by the cancellation token.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, `CancellationTokenSource` is used to start the cancellation (for example, by a another/parent thread, ).  `CancellationToken.Token` is the associated `CancellationToken` that you would pass to something like TaskFactory.StartNew() [as MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.iscancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested` property indicates whether
>   cancellation has been requested for this token source, such as due to a call to its Cancel method.

And then the `Task` would monitor the `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` to determine when to shut down.

For property `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets whether cancellation has been requested for this token.

To sum up, I would like to tell that `CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested` is used to associate `CancellationToken` with `TaskFactory.StartNew()`. And `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` is used to define whether cancellation has been requested for this token. Moreover, `IntelliSense` has the same definition for `CancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested` and for `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`.