# How does the timeout apply on StreamSocket.readAsync()?

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-8.1, stream-socket-client

I have created the streamSocket that received the stream of media. I want to read the stream on this socket and also want to apply readTimeout. So that I have applied it using CancellationTokenSource. As per my requirement, if I cant read within timeout limit, I dont want to close this socket. However, applying cancellation token causes the socket close in my program.

Is there any way to apply time out without closing the socket?

```
await socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 8,     InputStreamOptions.None).AsTask(cts.Token);
```

Comment: Socket applications should generally be reading *all* the time, in a continuous loop. If you restructure your application to do so, you'll find that you won't need to cancel reads at all.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I have restructured my code as per your suggestion.